# Blackjack Program

Tags: c++, blackjack

I have to create a BlackJack program that plays with 7 players and a Dealer. I have to use a switch or and if statement for the suit type and this statement can only be used once.

What I know is not working is the Shuffle() function:

When I run without debugging it will give me and output like (A of Spades) twice
but I put an array so it would not duplicate a card.

However when I do debug it and get into every line of code the output is would give me two non-duplicated cards.

I am also having trouble calculating player totals a requirement"Write a function to deal two cards to each player.", How do I add the two cards to an array that has no definite size?

This web albulm contains full requirements of my project:

https://picasaweb.google.com/zaidalmas/November172011?authuser=0&authkey=Gv1sRgCNXrltTFwZnYNQ&feat=directlink

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void Header();
void Shuffle(int&, char&);
void Dealer();
void Deal();
void Another_Card();
void Fin_Dealer();
void WLT();

void gotoxy(int h, int w)
{
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle ( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

if ( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hConsole )
    {
    COORD pos = {h, w};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition ( hConsole, pos );
    }
return;
}

int main()
{
Header();
Dealer();
Deal();
WLT();
gotoxy(0,19);
return 0;
}

void Header()
{
cout <<"\t\t\tWelcome to BlackJack!\n\n";
gotoxy(3,3);
cout <<"Dealer Player1 Player2 Player3 Player4 Player5 Player6 Player7 "<<endl;
return;
}
void Shuffle(int& num, char& suit)
{
int cards[52], dup[52];
int card;
srand(time(NULL));

for(int i = 0; i <52; i++)
    dup[i] = 0;

    card = rand() % 52;

    while(dup[card])
        card = rand() % 52;

    dup[card] = 1;
    suit = char(card/13 + 3); //display suit
    num = card % 13;

    switch(num)
        {
        case 0: cout<<setw(6)<<right<<" A"<<suit;
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9: cout<<setw(6)<<right<<" "<<num + 1<<suit;
            break;
        case 10: cout<<setw(6)<<right<<" J"<<suit;
            break;
        case 11:cout<<setw(6)<<right<<" Q"<<suit;
            break;
        case 12:cout<<setw(6)<<right<<" K"<<suit;
            break;
        default:cout<<setw(6)<<right<<"Error";
            break;
        }
return;
}
void Dealer()
{
int i = 0;
int num = 0;
char suit;
for(i = 4;i <6; i++)
{
    gotoxy(0,i);
    Shuffle(num, suit);
}
return;
}
void Deal()
{   
int i = 0;
int num = 0;
int row = 4;
char suit;

for(i = 1; i < 8; i++)
{
    gotoxy(i*8, row);
    Shuffle(num,suit);
}
if(playertotal <=20)
{
    Another_Card()
}
return;
}
void Another_Card()
{
return;
}
void Fin_Dealer()
{
return;
}
void WLT()
{
return;
}
```

Comment: `How do I add the two cards to an array that has no definite size?` It  may not be definite but it has a maximum size if you do not want to use containers that can be resized(21/2). Vegas / Atlantic City use more than one deck in the shoe. Dealer generaly does not hit above 16. Some rules allow to hit on a soft 17 (A+6)

Answer (score 1):

Your shuffle code isn't keeping track of what cards have already been dealt. Each time you call it, it re-initializes the dup array making it possible to deal the same card multiple times.

As a suggestion, create two subroutines. One shuffles a deck of cards once for each hand. The second deals from that shuffled deck.

Answer (score 0):

Your Shuffle() loop does something like this:

```
dup[i] = 0;
...
/* Generate card */
...
dup[card] = 1;
```

Consider what happens when iteration x of this loop generates card x+n. When you get to iteration x+n, you overwrite dup[x+n].

The first line arbitrarily sets the current index to 0 (false). The rest of your Shuffle function indexes the dup[] array based on the random 'card'. You are setting a random index in your dup[] array to '1' (true), then potentially overwriting it on a later iteration, making the dup[] array incorrect.

Technically, one should not have to initialize the array items to 0. That *should* happen automatically. But, for various reasons, it is generally considered good practice to initialize the entire array up front anyway. So, do a quick loop:

```
for(int i = 0; 52 > i; ++i)
    dup[i] = 0;
```

So, the quick answer is to remove the dup[] = 0 line in the for loop.